# TextCellRenderer in Xamarin.UWP

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, xamarin.windows

How could we set TextCell height with padding/margin in Windows Universal Project using Xamarin.Forms?

I tried following [Custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) in Native project:

```
class CustomTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
    {
        var d = base.GetTemplate(cell);
        //Set something here???
        return d;
    }
}
```

but couldn't find any property to be set.

There is function to set dependency property of `DataTemplate` but I coudn't figure it out, what  will be the dependency property name for height to set?

```
d.SetValue(???DependencyProperty???, value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the TextCell is a built in cell, it's optimized and designed to be used as is. However you can create a custom DataTemplate based on the TextCell template and return that instead.

You can find the original template in the Xamarin.Forms [source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d9288eee6e6f197364a64308183725e7bd561f9/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml#L383). Then in the UWP platform project's `App.xaml`, define your new DataTemplate inside the ResourceDictionary with a different key:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTextCell">
    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="0 10 0 10"
            Margin="5"
            Text="{Binding Text}"
            Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />

        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Detail}"
            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
            x:Name="detail"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and access it inside the custom renderer with:

```
return App.Current.Resources["MyTextCell"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
```

Comment: Atleast I'm able to change the layout of textCell.